# 2D dynamically allocated global array in C++ Intel Parallel Studio 2015

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic, global

So I have used this site to good advantage to get what I believe to be the correct syntax for this but I am still stuck.

I'm bringing some pre existing fast hartley transform code in my project that currently uses FFT, and all of that is working except the size and overlap of the FHT are hard coded and I want to use the values in my FFT code to dynamically set the sizes at run time.

This requires 2D global arrays.

so I define the array outside of any function, so as to be global:

```
`double         **mInput;`
```

and in an init function I do this:

`

```
kWindowSize = (int)fftlen; //fftlen is a global from my existing program
mInput = new double*[kWindowSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < kWindowSize; ++i)
        mInput[i] = new double[2];

    printf("\nmInput pointer: %x mInput value: %f", (void *)&mInput, mInput);
    printf("\nfirst sample: %f second sample %f", mInput[0][0], mInput[0][1]);`
```

Which compiles and runs fine, however, in another function:

```
`printf("\n\n\n-->mInput pointer: %x mInput value: %f", (void *)&mInput, mInput);
    printf("\n-->first sample: %f second sample %f", mInput[0][0]);
    printf("\n-->second sample %f", mInput[0][1]);`
```

It crashes at the 2nd printf state (trying to access the values in the 2d array) with illegal write to location zero.

It seems as if the new statement inside the for loop is creating a local array vs. the global?

Since I got the dynamic allocation syntax from here I'm starting to wonder if this is a bug in the intel compiler?

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` over a `double **`?

Comment: It is not good to pass `mInput` when `printf` expects `%f`. `printf("\n-->first sample: %f second sample %f", mInput[0][0]);` in this case `printf` expects two arguments.

Comment: "This requires 2D global arrays" - says who? Globals can always be avoided if you want it enough.

Comment: `new double[2]`? Really?

Comment: The printf is just for debugging. The code crashes first time mInput is written to outside the init function.

Comment: Yes reworking the whole program (to use vectors vs. arrays) is possible, but not desirable as it's not my code and it's working now (with statically allocated arrays)

Comment: new double[2] is an example for this first array. There are others that have dynamic allocation for the 2nd dimension. Did you have some other Syntax to suggest?

Comment: There would have been if the `[2]` had been guaranteed. You could have made a 1D dynamic array of 1D static arrays. Simpler code and huge potential performance gains.

Comment: Here is a gag worth looking at: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op Bit of a rip-up to your code, but converts your array of arrays to a 1D array (better spatial locality and possibly better performance) and wraps the 1D array in a class that makes the 1D array LOOK like a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

I've took your idea of the global 2D array or double pointer and I've done this that may be of assistance to you without using `vector`, `list`, `array` but wrapped it into template class structure that uses smart pointers. I've done something like this:

```
#include <memory>
template <typename T = double>
struct Buffer {
    T* ptdatafield_ { nullptr };
    T* ptdata_ { nullptr };
    Buffer();
};

template<>
Buffer<double>::Buffer() {};

template<typename T = double>
class FFTBuffer {
public: 
    std::unique_ptr< Buffer<T> > unique_ptr_buffer_ { nullptr };

    union {
        T** pprawbuffer_ { nullptr };                       

        struct {
            std::shared_ptr<T> sub_shared_BufferIndexi_;
            std::shared_ptr<T> sub_shared_BufferIndexj_;
        };

        struct {
            T* rawIndexi_;
            T* rawIndexj_;
        };
    };

    explicit FFTBuffer( const Buffer<T>& buffer );      
    ~FFTBuffer() {};
};

template<>
FFTBuffer<double>::FFTBuffer( const Buffer<double>& buffer ) :
unique_ptr_buffer_( std::make_unique<Buffer<>>( buffer ) ), 
rawIndexi_( buffer.ptdatafield_ ), rawIndexj_( buffer.ptdata_ ) {    
}

int main() {
    Buffer<> buffer;
    FFTBuffer<> fftBuffer( buffer );

    Buffer<>* pBuffer = new Buffer<>();
    FFTBuffer<> fftBuffer2( *pBuffer );

    return 0;
}
```

Now this code does compile as is but I have not yet tested it with values or populating the internal arrays. I added the use of the public union with nameless structs. If alignment is correct it should match up as to the rows and columns in a 2D array such as a MxN matrix. This class stores a `unique_ptr<>` to a `Buffer` object that itself has two individual pointers, one for each dimension of the array. Then it uses that `Buffer` object to set the datafields within its internal public union of nameless structs and a double pointer. It's just multiple ways to access the same memory locations.

The idea is to generically form this association...

```
//.....

int i, j;
(fftBuffer.unique_ptr_buffer_.get()->ptdatafield_[i], fftBuffer.unique_ptr_buffer_.get()->ptdata_[j]) =  
fftBuffer.pprawbuffer_[i][j] = 
(fftBuffer.rawIndexi_[i], fftBuffer.rawIndexj_[j] =
(fftBuffer.sub_shared_BufferIndexi_.get()[i], fftBuffer.sub_shared_BufferIndexj_.get()[j])
```

Now I did not implement or include the `[]` overloaded operator(s) nor any other operators but they should not be that hard to implement. This should help visually to see how a 2D array is stored linearly in memory and to access or assign elements without the need of a "double for loop".

I would appreciate and except any and all feedback as towards the intentions of the design of this pseudo code for this algorithm with a short descriptive explanation of your decision. I'd like to hear both the pros and the cons as to why this is either "Good or Bad" code, where it could be improved on its design and implementation, and what other complications this might bring.

-- Personally I try to avoid stand alone globals unless if they are either const values that never change, or a static global variable such as a static global pointer to a singleton class object. --